# SearchApiException: Unknown or invalid item type node

Tags: commerce, search

I was working on site, when I got this error:

> WD php: SearchApiException: Unknown or invalid item type node. in
>   [error] search_api_get_datasource_controller() (line 1396 of
>   /var/www/luken/shop/sites/all/modules/search_api/search_api.module).
>   SearchApiException: Unknown or invalid item type node. w
>   search_api_get_datasource_controller() (linia 1396 z
>   /var/www/luken/shop/sites/all/modules/search_api/search_api.module).
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error]

Site is telling me about "Unexpected error", the above error I'm getting thanks to the Drush. Last thing that I did, was:

1. Removing one Product Display content type (I'm using Commerce),
2. Changing indexed fields in Search API,
3. Clearing the cache - after that, site was down.

I even don't know where to start with fixing this. I was trying to disable Search API module with Drush, but it appeared that I can't, because I'm getting above error all the time. I can access to /admin/modules but still I cannot disable Search API, because of unexpected error.

What can I do to fix this?

**Added:**
I deleted my search index, now I was able to disable Search API, but error still appears when entering the site. I checked log, there is an error:

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property
>   commerce_product. w EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (linia
>   339 z
>   /var/www/luken/shop/sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

Comment: See also: https://drupal.org/node/1903004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the site with the help of [Commerce Repair](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_repair):

> This module is designed to repair missing fields from various commerce entities. After installing, visit the menu item that does the repair, admin->store->config->Repair Commerce Fields (admin/commerce/config/repair). Once you've done that you can uninstall the module.